# What is the difference between running a binary and running with npm a script from package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

The situation is as follows:

E.g. there is a `package.json` like:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "next build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.0.26",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.43",
    "next": "9.4.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  }
}
```

Then running `npm run build` in the directory of the `package.json` executes the script assigned to the "build" key `next build`.

But directly running `next build` results in `bash: next: command not found`.

I did `npm install` so that all the dependencies defined in `package.json` get installed, though in the local `node_modules`-directory, which lies next to the `package.json`, where I can find the `next`-binary under `node_modules/next/dist/bin/`.

Using that like `node_modules/next/dist/bin/next build` works fine. So my assumption is that the command to install the dependencies does not encompass adding the `next`-binary to the path in the current environment to use it separately without the defined scripts in the `package.json`.

Comment: `npm run` adds `./node_modules/.bin/` to the path, you'll see `next` in there too (which the install *did* do, per the `bin` key in the package's `package.json`). Read https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-run-script.

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/4b8e539628d4c1ba9071185088b8ea661ca06389/packages/next/package.json#L44-L46

Answer (score 0):

NPM utility extends PATH non-trivially - to include `./node_modules/.bin` and additionally honors NPM workspaces support.

Plain Node.js knows nothing about `./node_modules/.bin` nor about NPM workspaces.

You could use NPM runtime context with `npm exec $CMD` syntax or `npx $CMD` if you omit versions - it will use local versions:

```bash
npm exec next build                 # use project version
npx next build
./node_modules/.bin/next build

npm exec next@latest build          # use latest version
npm exec next@14.0.3 -- next build  # use specific version
npm exec --package=next@14.0.3 -- next build
npx next@13.0.0 next build
npm exec --ws -- eslint ./*.js      # execute in each workspace!!
```